# services are null in spring controller + ZK

Tags: spring, zk

I'm trying to integrate zk with spring, but for somehow I can't make spring instances those service/manage objects :S

Controller,  ProductTypecontroller:

```
    @Controller
    public class ProductTypeController extends SelectorComposer {

        @Resource
        private ProductTypeService productTypeService;

        @Listen("onCreate = listbox#typeList")
        public void loadAll() {
            BindingListModelList model = new BindingListModelList(productTypeService.getAll(), false);
            typeList.setItemRenderer(new ProductTypeListRenderer());
            typeList.setModel(model);   
        }

       public void loadAll2(Listbox lb){
         List lista = productTypeService.getAll();
        BindingListModelList model = new BindingListModelList(lista, false);
        lb.setItemRenderer(new ProductTypeListRenderer());
        lb.setModel(model);              
    }

    }
```

the Zul

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" ?>
<zk>
    <hlayout>
    <div id="winDiv" apply="com.iknition.micutecake.controller.ProductTypeController">
        <vbox>
            <listbox id="typeList" width="450px" height="300px" >
                <listhead>
                    <listheader width="50px" label="id" sort="auto(id)" />
                    <listheader width="250px" label="name" sort="auto(name)" />
                    <listheader width="140px" label="description" sort="auto(description)" />
                </listhead>
            </listbox>
        </vbox>
    </div>
        </hlayout>
</zk>
```

I get NullPointerException because productTypeSerivce is null.

however, if I add `onCreate="loadAll2(self);"` to the listbox line in .zul
then it will call the method `loadAll2(Listbox lb)` in that way, productTypeService is not null, and everything works fine.

any idea why? or how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just have to replace

```
<div id="winDiv" apply="com.iknition.micutecake.controller.ProductTypeController">
```

with

```
<div id="winDiv" apply="${productTypeController}">
```

so zk will use spring resolver to resolve the controller